# Why was Folke Bernadotte assassinated by Zionist Jews, when he had helped many Jews to escape holocaust?

Tags: holocaust, zionism

I was reading this Wikipedia [article about the White Buses operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Buses) to rescue Jews from concentration camps.

It looks like, based on the article and other information that [Folke Bernadotte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folke_Bernadotte) was involved in this operation through this person named [Felix Kersten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Kersten).

The question I wanted to ask is about why Folke Bernadotte was later murdered by Zionist Jews? As Zionist Jews I would have thought that they would have been thankful to anyone who had helped the cause of the Jewish people?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of basic research.

Comment: Their way of saying thank you. No good deed remains unpunished.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article you linked to has the explanation. Bernadotte was killed by the Lehi group, also known as the Stern Gang.

> The group regarded Bernadotte as a stooge of the British and their Arab allies, and therefore as a serious threat to the emerging state of Israel. Most immediately, a truce was in force and Lehi feared that the Israeli leadership would agree to Bernadotte's peace proposals, which they considered disastrous.

After the Holocaust, some Zionists decided that their only hope of safety lay in the use of force against anything they considered a threat. Bernadotte's past actions didn't count for much if they considered him a threat later on.