# Is there a basis for this tale of Eisenhower blessing & Patton's curse?

Tags: world-war-two, jews, holocaust, concentration-camps, eisenhower

**After discussion:**

1. The "magical" part here is beside the point, I just quoted the legend. I'm insterested with the factual things, some of which might have happened. For example, it's very plausible Eisenhower mentioned a blessing by holocaust survivor in his speeches. His books and attitude shows IMHO he was very sympathetic to DPs in general, Jewish or not.
2. As requested, other sources citing a visit and meeting with a Rabbi is in [this JPost column](https://www.jpost.com/opinion/columnists/the-first-word-survivors-yom-kippur-september-1945). Here they describe a request for traditional "Four Species" for the Succot holday.

There’s a recent tale published in Ultra Orthodox newspapers in Israel, which tells the following story:

When Eisenhower and Patton visited a displaced persons camp, they talked to Rabbi [Halberstam](https://www.worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n80097466/), using a Rabbi chaplain as a translator.

They allegedly both asked him for a blessing. He blessed Eisenhower to fill the highest position in the US, and “blessed” Patton to die in unnatural way, due to his antisemitism. The chaplain then told Patton his blessing was “may your name be set in stone”.

Eventually, Patton died in a car accident, and Eisenhower became president, and even mentioned the blessing in his memories and his speeches.

This folklore quotes Rabbi Silver/Zilber as the translator, a visit in Yom Kippur to Feldafing. [There was such a visit of both generals,](https://collections.ushmm.org/search/catalog/pa1040155) but I saw many different details of the content of this visit.

I was wondering what’s the source of this tale. I assume there’s some grain of truth in it, and I thought it might be a more common knowledge to history lovers.

I tried to skim Eisenhower's books "Crusade in Europe" and searched the indices there, and had a look at "Eisenhower and the Jews" book, but couldn't find any clue.

Origin of this tale: *[Hebrew at Ultra Orthodox newspaper](https://www.facebook.com/561051247250664/photos/pb.561051247250664.-2207520000.1518984497./1699440316745079/?type=3)* or *[bhol.co.il](https://www.bhol.co.il/news/899477)*

Is that completely baseless? How can I find out more about the source of this folklore tale?

Apparently I found evidence to this visit, with clear indications that the Jewish DPs there were not content with Patton's attitude:

[image: nyt oct 2 1945]
[image: nyt oct 2 1945 pt2]
[image: nyt oct 2 1945 pt3]
[image: nyt oct 2 1945 pt4]

Also evidence that Patton inspected the same camp around the time Eisenhower was there

[image: Patton inspected camp]

And another piece:[image: Evening Star]

Comment: So the source isn't even really the newspaper, but a facebook post *claiming* to be from the newspaper?

Comment: Frankly, sounds like silly folk story about the old wizard ;) Would not be so bad if thousands did not die in those same concentration camps, without the help of wizard's magic.

Comment: @rs.29 it's a "known" tale I read in more than one place, the facebook paper has photo from the paper. Typically UO papers do not have internet websites, since using the internet is controversial than.

Comment: @rs.29 I tend to agree, however the tale contained many specific details and names. And the visit to Feldafing did happen, there seem to be a meeting with a Rabbi there in other sources I found.

Comment: Please add the "other sources" into the question, as well as an exact translation of the relevant identifying parts as an English quote. The date given seems to be as year 5705 corresponds to https://collections.ushmm.org/search/catalog/pa1040155 but for Sep 17 '45,  I don't understand the language used around 'in the midst of Yom Kippur' well enough…

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich Visit to camp (by both generals) is plausible, check sources for dates then cross-check with other documents. "Magic" part of the story is kinda ...tacky... considering what really happened at camps.

Comment: @rs.29 the "magic" has very little sense in almost no way. However having a Rabbi hostility to Patton, given his general attitude to jewish DP as testified in "Eisenhower and the Jews", is pretty plausible. And this is the historical part I'm curious about. Also a blessing by holocaust surviver could be mentioned in Eisenhower's speeches, matches his character IMHO. So could be based on correct facts mentioned by Eisenhower.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich So what is your story ? Two US generals visit the camp, they talked to esteemed Rabbi, one of them is nice so he gets a blessing, one of them is not so nice so he gets a curse . I suppose if someone kept the records of the talks, this could be proven or disproven.

Comment: Certainly it would be strange if Eisenhower had left such a supernatural prediction out of his memories, as people usually like all the data that confirms that what they do is right. And wouldn't he have called back that Rabbi to have him as his personal curser (for example, to curse Krushev)? Absence of evidence for such an astounding event (a Rabbi predicting, or even better, "directing" the lifes of top American generals) makes it appear a lot like a fabrication, since anyone in favor of Judaism would be fast to provide that evidence.

Comment: On a related note, the news piece (at least as you explain it) does not sound like something a good journalist would write. It is missing the explanation of who is putting forward that story. Was it told by the Rabbi? The translator? One of the generals? Someone else at the scene? A good story would have its source, even if it was indirect ("Mr. X, who was told about it by the Rabbi when they met at a dancing class")

Comment: @SJuan76 the source is Rabbi Silverman/Zilberman, a chaplain in the US army, and the translator between Rabbi Halberstam and the two Generals. It's a religious newspaper, typically telling "stories" about Jewish Rabbis. Couldn't identify him, maybe this https://www.nli.org.il/en/newspapers/bbh/1965/06/25/01/article/184/?e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN%7ctxTI--------------1

Comment: Please also add a proper source attribution for the newspaper snippets: which paper, date, (online where?)…

Answer (score 6):

This is obviously a fairy tale.

- Patton didn't die in a taxi, but was injured in a [car accident](https://www.nationalww2museum.org/war/articles/general-george-s-patton-jr-death) in his own staff car. He died due to complications of his injuries.
- [Eisenhower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwight_D._Eisenhower) became president in 1953. It's not impossible he planned to run for president in the future, but 8 years in advance is stretching it.
- The story comes from ultra orthodox sources. In general, not exactly unbiased, to say the least. *(The same applies to any ultra orthodox whatever, not necessarily Jews.)*
- There are no independent sources (staff officers, attendants, journalists) confirming the story.
- It fits the expected narrative: Eisenhower, not antisemitic: good and Patton, antisemitic: bad. Eisenhower is rewarded, Patton is punished. The rabbi couldn't curse all the guards of his camp? Why his liberator?

Comment: I tend to apriori agree, however I was not sure there's no source, and there are many sources for a visit in Feldafing, and some for a meeting with a Rabbi there. It's obviously shouldn't be taken as it is, but might be based on _something_.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich No, it doesn't have to be based on *something*. People make up stories. An Israeli carpenter is supposed to have walked over water. Is that based on *something*? Patton may have been antisemitic, but he never put people in KZ lagers. Even better: he liberated the inmates. Kind of harsh to curse a man for that.

Comment: Whole story seems like psychological crutch. Jews needed to persuade themselves they are still "God's chosen people" , so even those who are slightly against them, like Patton, are punished by death. Reality on the ground was of course much different.

Comment: @rs.29 added additional source for similar meeting with very different content, not sure how reliable jpost fact check are. Would love your help. Should I add a word-to-word translation of the legend in the UO newspaper?

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich I suppose you could add translation.

Comment: Also it seems to be anachronistic. Patton's anti-semetic views appear to have been largely unknown to the public prior to his being appointed military governor of Bavaria, and then getting fired for making intemperate remarks about the Nazi party. Even then, intemperate remarks of all kinds were a Patton specialty, so it wasn't clear that he had issues with Jews specifically until after his death when his diaries were published.

Comment: I did see a documentary where a former aide to Eisenhower claimed that right after V-E he did a comment on the idea of trying to become POTUS. Of course, it is the same kind of the story that the OP is trying to verify (minus the supernatural): not documented at the moment, no other witnesses, related only a lot of time later (so even an honest person could be mixing up his opinion about later events with what was actually said)...

Comment: **(1).** *The rabbi couldn't curse all the guards of his camp ?* - He could, and he probably did, hence the (obvious) explanation for Germany losing the war (!) **(2).** *Why his liberator ?* - [Why not](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/38293) ?

Comment: @T.E.D. regarding Patton's view. Do read Eisenhower and the jews. The chaplain who wrote the book testify that, e.g., Patton had armed guards on Jewish DP camps, and he required pass for them to exit. It seems to be clear then that his actions didn't favor Jewish DPs. Around p170 "I pointed out to Gen Smith the psychological affect of all this restrictions, personally ordered by Gen Patton..."

Comment: @SJuan76 the point was not Eisenhower was planning on POTUS, the point it he received a blessing, and mentioned it in his speeches. A plausible thing to do is to search his speeaches, especially speeches to Jewish communities, alas, I couldn't find those. Didn't find anything scanning "At ease" and "Crusade in Europe" and searching the index.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich - Again, the problem there is that he wasn't really known for favoring *anybody*. He got in big trouble once before that for saying basically that KIA soldiers were inherently inferior to wounded (because they were incompetent enough to get killed rather than merely wounded). For obvious reasons Gold Star families didn't take that very well, and US military culture was to put those families in particular on a pedestal. So this outraged nearly everybody, and was about the worst political blunder it was possible to make.

Comment: @T.E.D. my point is, unlike what you said, that Patton was just negative person, generally speaking, and Jewish people didn't have a particular feelings against him. I tried to show a clear source that shows this is untrue, and Jewish DPs back then had clear qualms specifically targetted at Patton specifically.

Comment: @T.E.D. have a look at the NYT piece I added, Jewish complained about Patton back then, we have every reason to believe a Rabbi in this specific camp would be hostile to Patton. It seems this story is far from fairy tale, but very likely to happen (that is, a Rabbi in Feldafing, visit by Eisenhower, hostile to Patton sympathetic to Eisenhower).